# chartjs grouped stacked bar charts rotate canvas text/labels

Tags: javascript, canvas, bar-chart, chart.js, stacked-chart

Is there a way to rotate text for individual bar in chart js grouped stacked bar chart? I've been able to replicate some of the examples here to do the grouped stacked bar on chartjs but I need to rotate the text in canvas to accommodate all the displayed data. Text rotation of -80deg. Also if possible to put the bar label at the bottom of the individual bar.
Currently experementing this code but still not working.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bm88sd5c/)

```
helpers.each(self.getMeta().data, function (rectangle, index) {
    ctx.rotate(-80 * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.translate(-150, 50);
    ctx.fillText(this.getDataset().stack, rectangle._model.x, rectangle._model.y)
}, this);
```